# Any Better Solution for Sax Parser Unit Testing

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing, parsing, junit

I am working on a legacy code, which parses XML by taking clob from database. Database has many clobs it's designed to loop and parse till it reaches end.

Parser Used : SAX Parser(JAVA)
Problem Description : Lengthy Unit Test

I managed to write junit for this by creating a new parser and getting data there and checking assertions but, its very huge with many hashmaps.
I have been browsing all articles and sites to see if there is any way I can write junit for parser, where we can directly validate attributes without creating a new parser. i.e, using main class and validate datatypes in that parser class itself like we normally do for Java classes. Please let me know if there is a better solution to this.

Comment: Have you looked at http://www.xmlunit.org ?

Comment: Nope. I will look into it.  Thank you.